# Using HTML5 File API to upload Photos via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, html, facebook-graph-api, fileapi

I'm trying to make a photo organizing Facebook application without using server-side process.

Now I can preview photos by using FileReader object's readAsDataURL method, such as...

```
var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
        var imgObj = $(document.createElement('img')).attr('src',reader.result).appendTo('#image_preview_wrapper');
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}, false);
```

The question is how to post the image data to Facebook.
I'm trying to do something like

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(e) {
    var data = reader.result;
    FB.api('/me/photos','post',{ image : data },function(res){
        alert(res);
    });
}
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```

In this case, I can't set enctype="multipart/form-data" and I'm getting 400 Bad Request.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I don't know the answer but in case you didn't know - `$(document.createElement('img'))` could be simplified to `$("<img>")`.

Comment: Have you found your solution ? According to documentation in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/, in your FB.api call, instead of "image", it should be "source" and content should be of type "multipart/form-data"...